# Problems with removing a node in xml with C# UWP

Tags: c#, xml, uwp

When I attempt to remove a node from the root I accomplish it but at the end of the document the nodes after the removed node returns to appear after the root end tag.

The xml document is like this before:

```
<User>
   <Name>Antonio</Name>
   <Last Name>Gonzalez</Last Name>
   <Password>AntonioGonzalez123</Password>
</User>
```

After remove the child "Last Name":

```
<User>
 <Name>Antonio</Name>
 <Password>AntonioGonzalez123</Password>
</User>lez<Last Name>
   <Password>AntonioGonzalez123
</Password></User>
```

My code in C# is:

```
public void RemoveNodes(string node)
{
   Doc.Load(path);

   Doc.DocumentElement.RemoveChild(Doc.DocumentElement.GetElementsByTagName(node)[0]);

   Doc.Save();
}
```

Comment: As far as I'm aware, there is no parameter-less `Save` method on what looks like `XmlDocument`. So what is `Doc` and how is `Save` implemented? It looks like you're not truncating the file stream before writing to it.

Comment: doc is XmlDocument Doc = new XmlDocument;

Comment: As @CharlesMager said, no `Save` method for `XmlDocument` class. Please upload the correct minimal reproduced project.

Comment: To the load and save I use a IsolatedStorageFileStream controlled by a class I created separately